# question about solution of equation complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A friend just told me that the equation $e^{z^2}=0$ has solution. Is it true?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The map $w\mapsto e^w$ takes the complex numbers onto the **non-zero** complex numbers.